# How can an admin signOut a user from session database using next-auth session?

Tags: authentication, next.js, redis, next-auth, credential-providers

I'm coming from express-session where an admin can sign out any user using his/her sessionID using session store  i.e

const store = req.sessionStore

how can i implement the same using next-auth session?

I tried to search the user in the session database using his/her information (email) but i think that's not the best practice

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.